# Using the robocopy to copy specific files just if NOT exist

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

I'm using the robocopy in batch files that automatic updating our softwares.

that is the command I'm currently use:

```
ROBOCOPY "%Source%" "%Destination%" /MIR /PURGE /E /NP /R:5 /LOG+:"%Destination%\Update.log" /TS /FP /TEE /XF "%Destination%\SettingsA.config" "%Destination%\SettingsB.config" "%Destination%\SettingsC.config" "%Destination%\Trace.log" "%Destination%\Error.log" "%Destination%\update.log" /XD "%Destination%\Logs"
```

That command exclude the config and log files, and it's works great.

The problem is that if the config files does not exist, I have to copy the default files from the source directory (`%Source%\SettingsA.config`, `%Source%\SettingsB.config` and `%Source%\SettingsC.config` in that case)

Currently, if that config files will be exist on the source directory they will be overwritten on the destination directory.

Because the source directory is from a mapped network drive it will much better to perform it with a single robocopy command.

Is it possible?

Comment: What about [`robocopy`](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)`"%Source%" "%Destination%" /E /XC /XN /XO /XX …`?

Comment: @aschipfl It doesn't meet the requirement to install / update the software, it just will copy not existing files. (and will not overwrite the old version)

Comment: Well, what about removing `/XO` then? or reading the documentation after all? Type `robocopy /?` into a Command Prompt window and read the help, particularly the `File Selection Options` section…

Comment: Before I went here I have read the documentation well of course, a little bit insulting :) Anyway removing the /XO still will not make it better, I need to overwrite any changed file whether newer or older (excluding the specified config and log files). reinstalling should work that way. The Gerhard's answer is perfect for me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To demonstrate what I meant, test each config file for existence, then create a parameter and exclude if it does in fact exist.

```
if exist "%Destination%\SettingsA.config" set "confa="%Source%\SettingsA.config""
if exist "%Destination%\SettingsB.config" set "confb="%Source%\SettingsB.config""
if exist "%Destination%\SettingsC.config" set "confc="%Source%\SettingsC.config""
ROBOCOPY "%Source%" "%Destination%" /MIR /PURGE /E /NP /R:5 /LOG+:"%Destination%\Update.log" /TS /FP /TEE /XF %confa% %confb% %confc% "%Destination%\SettingsA.config" "%Destination%\SettingsB.config" "%Destination%\SettingsC.config" "%Destination%\Trace.log" "%Destination%\Error.log" "%Destination%\update.log" /XD "%Destination%\Logs"
```

Comment: You'll have to remove the words `file` and `dirs`…

Answer (score 0):

You could just copy source to a temporary directory, move destination to the temp, and move temp to destination.

Comment: The source is on a network drive, I need to save network traffic.

Comment: @KBar, you could use `/XO` flag. But you need to make destination newer than source, then it would do what you need. You can change file modification time with powershell 

       `(Get-Item 'dir/*.config').LastWriteTime = Get-Date` (to change to latest)